# Issue with installing Maven

Tags: maven-plugin

We are trying to install maven on **aws**. As part of our instructions after installing the file/updating environment variables, we need to go on cmd, remote to C:\ then put maven "plugin:download" to download the required jars! but I'm faced with this error.

can someone help?

[CMD error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oeyw.png)

Comment: It's great that you have a screenshot from your error: Consider copying the error message from the screenshot under your post, so it's easier to read by others.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have network connectivity issues. Consider setting your proxy configurations for Maven: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html